# Use mixedCor to compute the correlation but meet some error

Tags: psych

When I use mixedCor to compute the correlation between continuous variables, I always meet this probelm[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhcEF.png). It seems that this is produced because some of the categorical variables have more than 8 levels. If I have to compute the correlation of these categorical variables, what should I do to make it compute successfully? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not as screen captures.

Comment: Welcome. You should not post code or anything else that is represented in textual form. Check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for more information.